# How to use messageListener properly when collections are updated in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, caching

I am trying to understand what's the most efficient way to use messageListeners when updating the MongoDB. I have the following code example:

```java
@Bean
public MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(MongoTemplate template) {
    MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer(template);
    messageListenerContainer.start();
    ChangeStreamRequest<TokenRequestorInfoEntity> request = ChangeStreamRequest.builder()
        .collection("Streamline_Trid")
        .publishTo(getTridListener())
        .build();
    try {
        Subscription subscription = messageListenerContainer.register(request, TokenRequestorInfoEntity.class);
    }
    catch(MongoTimeoutException | MongoExecutionTimeoutException | MongoSocketClosedException | MongoSocketReadTimeoutException | MongoSocketOpenException | UncategorizedMongoDbException e ) {
        logger.error("MongoDB Connection failure while registering listener:"+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.error("MongoDB Connection failure:"+ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    return messageListenerContainer;
}
```

In a multi-collection scenario, should I create multiple message listeners in which multiple caches are updated? or usually just one message listener is created per application.